# upload multiple files using ember-file-upload

Tags: ember.js

to upload file in ember js we are using [ember-file-upload](https://github.com/tim-evans/ember-file-upload)

in the documentation I can see they have options to select multiple files, it creates a queue and upload photo one by one. so suppose there are 3 files in a queue it sends 3 request.
What I am trying to achieve is send multiple files in a single request only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That plugin does not seems to support what you want. You can try to extract files (instances of [`File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File), I see that [file queue service](https://github.com/tim-evans/ember-file-upload/blob/latest/addon/services/file-queue.js) should have them in `file` property) from queue and send them using jQuery and [formData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData). [This article](https://abandon.ie/notebook/simple-file-uploads-using-jquery-ajax) and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) contain example of uploading multiple files with jquery.